# Fetch Multi level select value using angular 2 and bootstrap

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2 with bootstrap but I am facing an issue in which I am not able to fetch all the the selected values of multilevel which I need to post it to and external API, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: can you share your code